# How to tell when an LM334 is limiting the current?

Tags: current-measurement, comparator

I have an LM334 based constant current source configured to supply a max of 1 mA.

The load has a variable impedance. My goal is to make an alarm of sorts when that impedance exceeds a threshold, and the way I want to do that is to detect when the 334 is in current limiting mode.

When it's passing less than 1 mA of current, I would expect it to be acting like a very low-value resistor, meaning that the voltage drop across it should be low. When the 1 mA of current is reached, it should begin to increase its resistance, thus increasing the voltage drop across it.

I'd like to measure the voltage drop and light an LED (really an optoisolator) when it exceeds a threshold.

At least, that's my thinking at the present. If anyone else has an idea of how to light an LED when an LM334 is actually limiting the current through it, that would work too.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGewrX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic, I1 represents the LM334. I don't see a way in circuitlab to represent an actual LM334, so the simulation likely won't operate correctly. R1 represents the ground impedance - the goal is to detect when it's value exceeds 10k. At the moment, I'm thinking I'd like to find a way to light an LED when Vin-Vout > 1V. From there, it's just a matter of tuning either the set resistor of the LM334 or the voltage threshold to trim to the setpoint.

Note as well that the actual circuit ground is on the *top* side of R1 - Vout is the ground potential for the purpose of this circuit. The actual earth is on the far side of R1.

Comment: Usually when a current supplied less than the current required, there is a voltage drop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd expect it to be minimal, however, since the 334 should be trying to pass as much current as it possibly can.

Comment: If it is a "constant" current source, why is the current "variable"?

Comment: @Tyler Think of it rather as a current *limiter*. If the load impedance is high, then the current will be much lower than the limit. If the load impedance is low, then the current will hit the limit. The LM334 in this case does not have an infinite voltage with which to overcome the load impedance.

Comment: **NOTE** VIN is 19V **peak** in optimal circumstances. With VAC at 90% of nominal and R2 at upper end of 5% tolerance, VIN is ~1V. With nominal VAC and R2 at upper end of 5% tolerance, VIN is ~11V.

Answer (score 3):

At 25C, the LM334 has a minimal drop-out voltage of about 0.9V between V+ and V-. If the V+ to V- drop is larger than that, the LM334 is in current regulation. Othewise, the load is getting the maximum voltage that the source can provide, and is not running at full current.

The simplest way to detect that would be by biasing a PNP transistor with a scaled-down version of the drop out voltage. When the drop out is at 1V below V+, the base would get, say, 0.7V, and the transistor would start conducting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUJ3xq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This isn't superbly accurate, but might work well enough. The current through the 25kOhm R1/R2 divider is 40uA/V, and that's an error source. The divider produces about 0.72V at 0.9V drop-out. You can increase the resistance of the divider if you can use a larger load resistor R3 or a higher-gain transistor. The ILIM output is logic-compatible as long as V+ is not too high. Otherwise, you'll need a series resistor between ILIM and your MCU input.

You can also simply use a high- or low-side current monitor/comparator. E.g. if you can waste about a volt of headroom and your load can be floating, you can use LTC1540 with a 1.18k sense resistor, you'll get logic output straight out of it.

Comment: ¡Me gusta! - particularly because it's all passive components, which saves me having to cough up an isolated power supply. Can R3 be replaced with an opto-isolator diode and series resistor? I need to use an opto between this circuit and the logic systems for safety.

Comment: @nsayer Q1 is anything but passive. Given that the V+ impedance is 150k? Nope, it won't work. Anyway, the circuit above was designed for loads that don't go very low impedance; RLOAD needs to be above ~4kOhm for it to work. You need a different design, and I question the need for a current source. A couple of resistors and a comparator with built-in reference would do the job in a much simpler fashion. Hint: you're trying to detect whether the bottom of a resistive divider is 10k or less.

Comment: The current limiter is intended to limit the amount of ground leakage. Excessive ground leakage will cause a GFCI to trip (at around 5 mA). It's also intended to at least attempt to desensitize the circuit to the tolerance variation of the 150k resistor and the supply voltage.

Comment: Would using a FET instead of a BJT help? If not, perhaps using the FET to turn the opto LED on and off (Ilim -> gate)?

Comment: @nsayer The leakage is set by the value of R2. Remember that this circuit must act appropriately during faults - and then the LM334 is a short. So what you do is connect R2 directly between L and PE terminals. R2 completely determines the behavior of the system, when looked at from outside, and sets the leakage current. Given that your threshold is 10k RLOAD, what does even 10% tolerance on the whole thing mean? Nothing much. Furthermore, I think it's rather crazy that you allow such high ground impedance (10k).

Comment: FWIW, faults will cause the power to be disconnected. It's not shown here because it's a function of the logic circuit, which is beyond the discussion here. If that weren't the case, then the circuit ground would effectively be at a high voltage, which isn't great.

Comment: @nsayer Without seeing the full schematic I don't buy that a single fault won't cause the whole thing to act as if there was R2 between L and PE terminals. I mean, do you have a fault tree that shows that every failure results in the power getting disconnected? If you don't, then I bet there's a failure mode that turns it into a static resistor :) Especially that such circuits will have a tendency to have failure cascades when exposed to transient overvoltage conditions - not an uncommon thing. What's the rationale behind the 10kOhm ground impedance cutoff? I'd think 100Ohm is a lot already.

Comment: I looked a little closer. There's another reason this may not work. The actual circuit ground is the top side of the Rload of your schematic. The collector of the 3906 can't have an independent path to true ground.

Comment: Is it *possible* for the power disconnect to fail? Sure. In this case, it would require the contactor to get welded closed or the controller watchdog to fail AND for the ground impedance to be excessive all at the same time. But this is all about meeting UL standards, and the UL standard for EVSEs doesn't require you to engineer around multiple failures. The more reasonable likelihood is that the ground impedance is excessive at installation and it closes the relay long enough to figure that out and opens. The 100 ohms per volt is from the same UL spec.

Answer (score 1):

Any (real) current source will have a voltage limit beyond which it will not deliver a constant current. In the case of the LM334, it is rated with a voltage drop of 2.5V. Below 2.5V, the impedance may increase. The **typical** performance is shown in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm134.pdf) in this graph:

[image]

So for low currents, it might be delivering more-or-less constant current at 0.7V and for higher currents, more than 1V. This will vary over temperature and from unit to unit, that's what they mean by 'typical'.

So if you monitor the voltage across the LM334 (perhaps with a comparator) you can have a good idea of whether it is working or not. If the voltage is more than 2.5V (for appropriate current settings) you know it is working. If it's less than that it may or may not be working (there is no *minimum* voltage below which is it is guaranteed to not work).

Edit: So if the LM334 is connected low side and sinking 1mA, and you want to know when the forward voltage drops below 1V you can use a comparator with a 1V reference. The reference could be derived from a regulated supply voltage such as 5V with a voltage divider. The comparator could be something like half an [LM393](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000465.pdf).

Comment: All of that is true. The question at hand is how best to detect when the voltage across the LM334 exceeds a threshold.

Comment: It depends on GREATLY on how the LM334 is connected (high side or low side, for example) and how much your current is and how much error you can tolerate (any monitor circuit will lower the output impedance). One option would be a TL431 or LMV431, but that's just one of an almost infinite number of possibilities. It's not possible to give a good answer without much more information (such as  a complete schematic and accuracy requirements).

Comment: FWIW, in this case Rset is 68 ohms for a 1mA current limit. The detection threshold would be something like 1V.

Comment: It's connected high-side. The circuit in this case is a Ground Continuity Monitor. A small current from an AC supply is intentionally "leaked" to ground. If that current doesn't flow, then that's an error. The LM334 is supplied by rectified 120VAC via a 150k ohm fusible 2W resistor. In the old circuit, the output drives an optoisolator's LED, but that circuit isn't accurate or sensitive enough. The trip point is intended to be no higher than 100 ohms per volt - 10k. The intent now is to connect the output to ground and measure the voltage drop across it instead.

Comment: Please post a complete schematic.

Comment: @nsayer That shouldn't be a comment. Please edit your question and delete the comment. It belongs in the question.